# Selecting a wide range of value in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

so here's I've this code in Excel VBA

```
Sub GetValue()

Dim rRH, rYear, r1 As Range
Dim RowIndex, ColIndex, yearRow As Integer
Dim rh1 As Integer
Dim rh1Pct As Double
Dim year As String

RowIndex = 30
yearRow = 10

Do While RowIndex < (RowIndex + yearRow)
    Set rRH = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CF-Apar").Range("M" & CStr(RowIndex))

    If rRH.Value <> "" Then
        rh1 = rRH.Value
        year = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CF-Apar").Range("A" & CStr(RowIndex)).Value
        Exit Do
    End If

    RowIndex = RowIndex + 1
Loop

RowIndex = 12
rh1Pct = Range("D12").Value

ColIndex = 0
Set rYear = Range("D120")
Do While ColIndex < yearRow

    If CInt(year) > CInt(rYear.Value) Then
        Set r1 = rYear
        r1.Offset(123, 0).Value = "0"
    End If

    If year = rYear.Value Then
        rYear.Offset(123, 0).Value = rh1 * rh1Pct
        Exit Do
    End If

    Set rYear = rYear.Next
    Set r1 = r1.Next
Loop
End Sub
```

the code is to change or move the value in current cell whenever a value in CF-Apar worksheet is changed, but the current code is only cover one range (for this case, it's M, in CF-Apar index), the question is, how do I add more range cell, for example from M30 to Q40, how is the best way do achieve this?

Comment: You need to add one more loop which will 'cover' `Do...Loop` which you already have. You could try to use `For i=13 to 17` which will reflect columns `M to Q`. But, to make it efficient you need to change internal references of your ranges: from `.Range("M" & Cstr(rowindex)` to `.Cells(rowindex, i)`. I hope you will cope with that suggestion.

Comment: okay, i understand what you mean, but i would prefer to do multiple loop (nested), any idea?

Comment: I've just suggested nested looping... `For i... >> Do while ...>> your loop internal code >> loop >> next i`

Comment: okay sir :D can you post that as an answer, plus some example would be nice to complete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in comments you need to use nested loops. This should go as follows (proposed code below is not tested):

```
'beginning of your sub here

'additional loop
Dim i as Byte
For i=13 to 17 'columns M to Q

'your loop but changed inside
Do While RowIndex < (RowIndex + yearRow)
    Set rRH = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CF-Apar").Cells(RowIndex, i)

    If rRH.Value <> "" Then
        rh1 = rRH.Value
        year = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CF-Apar").Cells(RowIndex, i).Value
        Exit Do
    End If

    RowIndex = RowIndex + 1
Loop

RowIndex = 30
Next i
'rest of your code here
```

**EDIT** to explain questions from comments. Some alternative options for you:

**A)** base solution in my code

```
Set rRH = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CF-Apar").Cells(RowIndex,i)
'....
rh1 = rRH.Value   'for column i
```

**B)** alternative solution for your code

```
Set rRH = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CF-Apar").Cells(RowIndex, i)
Set rRH1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CF-Apar").Cells(RowIndex, "N")
'....
rh1 = rRH.Value   'for column i
rh2 = rRH2.Value  'for column N
```

**C)** alternative solution for your code

```
Set rRH = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CF-Apar").Cells(RowIndex, "M")
'....
rh1 = rRH.Value   'for column M
rh2 = rRH2.Offset(0, 1).Value  'for column N
```

and some other mixed options are available.

Comment: but supposed i want to set rh2, rh3, rh4, and so on for the next variable, how can I do that? while i only got **rh1 = rRH.Value** how can i assign rh2, rh3, and so on?

Comment: is it for next columns? like rh2 for column N, rh3 for column O, etc...?

Comment: you can always do it in this way: `Set rRH2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CF-Apar").Cells(RowIndex, "N")`... and so on...

Comment: yes, exactly as you said, rh2 is for column N, rh3 is for column O :)

Comment: so, see edit in the answer, some options provided and some other you could figure out on your own...